# Run jQuery script in window application vb.net with in webrowser

Tags: webbrowser-control, vb.net-2010, run-script

There is a dropdown list in a HTML page:

I want to programmatically change the selected value from the dropdown list using:

```
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript
```

Executing

```
$('#year_sel').val('2012').change();
```

in FireBug console works but the same statement does not work when I use

```
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("$('#year_sel').val('2012').change();")
```

How can I get that to work using `InvokeScript`?

Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a written out example which had been working for years:

```
Dim jsstrings As Object() = {"$('#year_sel').val('2012').change();"}
WebBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("eval", codestring)
```

It is using javascripts eval plus a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

`WebBrowser.Document.InvokeScript` expects a JavaScript function name, rather than a script fragment. The function has to be already available in the page's global JavaScript namespace. You can do what you're after by using JavaScript's `eval`, [here is how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19242163/1768303).