# webbrowser component interaction with webpage

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have a windows form application with a browser component in it.

My goal is to load a webpage and pass variable's from the webpage to the form.
Maybe trough java script.
But i cant find out if it is even possible to pass variable's from the webrowser component to the the rest of the form.

Comment: You can call the page's JavaScript from `WebBrowser` (or inject some new one) and get back any page's variables this way. More details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19002650/1768303

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the web page with `Webbrowser.Navigate()` then get the html of the loaded page using the `WebBrowser.DocumentText` property.
You have to read this property after the page is loaded so use it in the `DocumentCompleted` handler.

Comment: how do i use WebBrowser.DocumentText to get the html?

Comment: `string html = WebBrowser.DocumentText;` just add it to the event handler