# Browser-based testing tool which is not broken?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, selenium

Sorry for the controversial title here!

I've done a fair bit of browser-based testing (of JS-heavy web pages), using Selenium and Selenium-based libraries like Capybara. It has always been a big pain in the neck to get the test suites to work consistently. Yes, I know that rather than inserting calls to `sleep()` here and there, you are supposed to wait for DOM elements to become visible, or meet other conditions, yadda yadda. That's all good, and it does help a bit. I'd think that I wasn't doing it quite right, if it was not for...

If it was not for the time, before I had ever written Selenium code myself, when the company I was consulting for hired a firm which specializes exclusively in writing Selenium test suites. They sent a guy who was supposedly an expert on Selenium, and he wrote a full test suite for our web app. Need I tell you what happened when we actually used the test suite?

I've concluded that the whole approach which tools like Selenium use is subject to a big race condition. You have a test process, and a separate browser process which talk over a socket. The test process sends queries to the browser to find out the state of the DOM, and **as the browser continues running**, computes what to do. Then it sends **a separate message** to the browser to simulate a click, or keystroke, etc.

If you have ever written multi-threaded programs, you know that just doesn't work. It's a "check-then-act" race. If the test process could **freeze** JS execution in the browser, query its state, issue simulated clicks/keystrokes, and then **unfreeze** the browser, then it would be OK. (Like using a lock to protect the critical section of a multi-threaded program.)

The only way I can think of getting around the race condition would be for each test case to be written in JS. That precludes test cases which span navigation across multiple pages, of course. You also need a way of resetting the page to a "clean" state at the beginning of each test case.

Does anyone know a tool/approach for testing in-browser JS "apps", which allows mortals like me to write test suites which run 100% consistently, **without** tearing out all my hair?

(PS. Another conclusion from experience with Selenium: A lot of free jQuery plugins have bugs which don't appear when humans are using the page, simply because they can't click as fast as Selenium can!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you seen [casperjs](http://casperjs.org/), which can run on top of phantomjs (a headless webkit browser) or slimerjs (a headless gecko browser)?

The [unit testing](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/testing.html#unit-testing) syntax is clean and friendly and it executes your tests in the context of the browser sequentially, using a method called evaluate().

Comment: I just heard about it recently. Have you ever written a test suite using CasperJS? How was your experience? Can it reload the page before running each test case?

Comment: Yes, I've written over 15 test suites for flows through various websites. It's very logical and is essentially a list of steps to perform. Crucially, it waits for pages to load and for the DOM to be ready before it starts executing your tests. It can definitely reload the page before each test - if you approach it as unit tests, each test would have a start() method, which loads a fresh page.

Comment: And the suites generally run consistently? They don't pass one second and fail the next?

Comment: I've seen two inconsistent behaviours. They may be dealbreakers for you:
1) When dealing with iframes, sometimes the callback that happens within casperjs when talking with phantomjs doesn't fire, so the script hangs. I've worked around this by aborting a request and sending it manually via casper.then(url);
2) When in a long running script - such as visiting each navigation link and timing how long it takes to return - I see "status=fail" as documented on `https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/issues/318` appear and the same timing as the previous successful URL. I've yet to work around this.

Comment: OK, one more question. Selenium RC also worked by injecting JS into a browser. They had some problems due to restrictions on what a JS script can do in a web page -- for example, it can't fill in a `input[type=file]` field. With CasperJS, do your test cases run under the same restrictions? (I know PhantomJS itself is driven through a JS interface, so I would expect that the JS controlling it should not have these restrictions, though I would expect JS loaded from a `<script>` tag in a page to be restricted.)

Comment: Regarding file uploads, the default example for form filling, [link](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html?highlight=form#fill), has a file upload, so it should work!  As far as I know, CasperJS is subject to the restrictions that PhantomJS's webkit implementation imposes and they themselves might be able to be subverted (for instance `--web-security=[true|false]` on [link](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference).

Answer (score 6):

Since the time that you answered this question, a new service has surfaced, [Ghost Inspector](https://www.ghostinspector.com). Browser-based UI testing without coding required. You have the option of doing manual steps in the app's editor, or you can use the Ghost Inspector Chrome extension to just record your interactions with the web app you're testing.

Ghost Inspector also video records every test run so you can see exactly what the testing agent browser saw. There are detailed logs about each test run, including a list of every URL that it clicked/visited on it's path. You can trigger Ghost Inspector tests with a trigger URL, so you can integrate it into your continuous deployment process.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to address your concern about the fact that the automation driving tool and the browser itself are the two separate processes, so the automation script is the subject to race conditions you've mentioned.

That's exactly why I tend to **write Web app automation scripts in-process**, so they operate on the same core UI event loop as the browser itself.

There's a great tool for this: [Microsoft WebBrowser Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You do need to have some C# skills to create an automation script. On the other hand, with the language features like `async/await`, coding `WebBrowser` automation is a breeze as it's naturally asynchronous (without those nasty `Thread.Sleep` and polling loops). On top of that, you can do all the usual automation tasks, for example:

- [Simulate a button click and asynchronously wait for navigation to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19063643/1768303).
- [Provide the file you want for `<input type=file>` fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18691219/1768303).
- [Inject and execute JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19002650/1768303).
- [Account for dynamic AJAX content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20934538/1768303).
- Run your test shell as a GUI app or [as a console app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19718530/1768303).

Comment: So essentially, rather than trying to control a web browser like FF/Chrome/IE, you write your own web browser which allows you to insert test code in the JS event loop. It's a good idea, I like it. Sounds like it's a Windows-only thing, which is unfortunate.

Comment: @AlexD, that's what it is, essentially. Indeed, limited to Windows only. OTOH, IE is still a major player, and this approach gives me the best intimacy for testing a web app under this platform.

Answer (score 1):

**It was called "Selenium".**  And it worked, but not well enough, largely because it was built entirely in JavaScript.  The Selenium Project moved on, adopting another system called "WebDriver" (*aka* Selenium 2.0), with tighter integration into the browsers, and now the browser authors are building the drivers into the browsers or as tightly-coupled add-ons (*e.g.* OperaDriver, ChromeDriver).

Comment: How does this answer the question? It sounds like you are just trying to clarify what is meant by "selenium" without addressing the core points of the question.

Comment: My point is that what the OP is requesting was the original design, and the very things he is asking for were considered design flaws that needed to be repaired.

Comment: Ross, you might want to try rephrasing your answer. The point you make in your comment is completely lost in how you worded your answer.

Comment: If Selenium RC was flawed, Selenium WebDriver is also flawed, just in a different way. Do you know a different tool, or a different way to use these tools, which doesn't suffer from the problems mentioned in my question?